# Automatic theme update after css edit doesn't work

Tags: codenameone

Has anyone ever encountered this problem? How to soolve?

A few weeks ago the automatic update of the theme after editing the css is not working. I get the following error in the log:

```
CSS watching failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.CSSWatcher.watch(CSSWatcher.java:190)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.CSSWatcher.run(CSSWatcher.java:336)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Did not find hotswap-agent.properties file
SourceChangeWatcher running.  Watching directories []
```

I'm using Apache Netbeans 13.
There are no errors in the css file apparently.

Comment: Are you using the Maven build or the Ant projects? There's some flakiness in the Ant builds so this might relate to that. It seems that you are using an older version since  the current code at [line 190](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/CSSWatcher.java#LL190C6-L190C6) won't throw a NPE.

Comment: I'm using Ant project.

Comment: This is often flaky with Ant projects. How did you get it to work with NetBeans 13 where the plugin is broken? I'm guessing [this commit](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/1beb5de293c56c63b32b68ba1f15fac09f3780c2) is the fix to that bug. But I'm not sure if it's available for Ant since we only maintain Maven builds now. You might be able to update the files manually from the maven repo. Just get the latest designer jar from a release.